# Regular expression to match a pattern either at the beginning of the line or after a space character

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been trying to dry up the following regexp that matches hashtags in a string with no success:

```
/^#(\w+)|\s#(\w+)/i
```

This won't work:

```
/^|\s#(\w+)/i
```

And no, I don't want to comma the alternation at the beginning:

```
/(^|\s)#(\w+)/i
```

I'm doing this in Ruby - though that should not be relevant I suppose.

To give some examples of matching and non-matching strings:

```
'#hashtag it is'        # should match => [["hashtag"]]
'this is a #hashtag'    # should match => [["hashtag"]]
'this is not a#hashtag' # should not match => []
```

Any suggestions? Am I nitpicking?

Comment: so example #3 works, but you want an equivalent regex without the grouping at the beginning for the lead in character?

Comment: For the stupider among us, please include an example input, which part you'd like to match and maybe a counterexample. "Hashtags in a string" doesn't match in my brain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/(?:^|\s)#(\w+)/i
```

Adding the `?:` prefix to the first group will cause it to not be a matching group, thus only the second group will actually be a matchgroup. Thus, each match of the string will have a single capturing group, the contents of which will be the hashtag.

Answer (score 5):

You can use.

```
/\B#(\w+)/i

"this is a #hash tag"      # matches
"#hash tag"                # matches
"this is not#hash tag"     # doesn't match
```

Comment: So that's a non-word boundary. Ingenious. Dry. Thanks!

Comment: This also matches `foo.#bar`. Not sure whether the OP wants that or not.

Comment: It's bad writing style, but it's plausible to assume author would have meant #bar as a separate word. All I wanted to avoid was text such as "Object#method," where I would assume author is talking Ruby and not hashtagging and all.

Answer (score 0):

This uses look-behind and I don't know if look behinds are supported in Ruby (I heard that they are not supported in JavaScript)

```
/(^#(\w+))|((?<= )#(\w+))/
```