# Regex to match hashtags in a sentence using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, twitter, hashtag

I am trying to extract hashtags for a simple college project using ruby on rails. I am facing issue with tags that include only numericals and with tags with no space.

```
text = "Pack my #box with #5 dozen liquor.#jugs link.com/liquor#jugs #2good #first#second"
```

The regex I have is `/(?:^|\s)#(\w+)/i` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796763/regular-expression-to-match-a-pattern-either-at-the-beginning-of-the-line-or-aft))

This regex returns `#["box", "5", "2good", "first"]`

How to make sure it only returns `#["box", "2good"]` and ignore the rest as they are not 'real' hashtags?

Comment: It's easy to filter the digital numbers. Maybe you should check 'linguistics' gem for ordinates. But I cannot use this gem due to some unknown character encoding problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try this regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)(?:(?:#\d+?)|(#\w+?))\s/i
```

**UPDATE 1:**
There are a few cases where the above regex will not match like: #blah23blah and #23blah23.
Hence modified the regex to take care of all cases.

*Regex:*

```
/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i
```

*Breakdown:*

- `(?:\s|^)` --Matches the preceding space or start of line. Does not
  capture the match.
- `#` --Matches hash but does not capture.
- `(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))` --Negative Lookahead to avoid ALL numeric characters
  between # and space  (or end of line)
- `(\w+)` --Matches and captures all word characters
- `(?=\s|$)` --Positive Lookahead to ensure following space or end of
  line. This is required to ensure it matches adjacent valid hash tags.

*Sample text modified to capture most cases:*

> #blah Pack my #box with #5 dozen #good2 #3good liquor.#jugs
>   link.com/liquor#jugs #mkvef214asdwq sd #3e4 flsd #2good #first#second #3

*Matches:*

Match 1:  blah
Match 2:  box
Match 3:  good2
Match 4:  3good
Match 5:  mkvef214asdwq
Match 6:  3e4
Match 7:  2good

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/MD6avgvV05)

**UPDATE 2:**

To exclude words starting or ending with underscore, just include your exclusions in the negative lookahead like this:

```
/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i
```

The sample, regex and matches are recorded in this [Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/PySQB8NvUY)

Comment: Just one more thing..its a big ask.. it also matches #_hello and #hello_, how to just allow #hello2_world or #hello_23?

Comment: Updated the regex with this. Please note that this will not match hashtags that would end in a punctuation mark (e.g., `blah blah #blah, blah blah #blah?`) because the last part of the regex (the positive lookahead) denotes that it needs to be a space or end of line. Hence the blah in `#blah,` and `#blah?` are not matched. If you need punctuated hash tags, then you need to OR the required punctuation symbols in the last positive lookahead. For e.g., to match the above 2 blahs, the last part would be `(?=\s|$|,|\?)` as shown [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/dClIEVMVbC)

Comment: thanks a lot! The answer explains everything. Wish i could give 10 votes :)

Comment: Your code is working well with me but some users in my site use arabic language for hashtags and your code not working do you have any ideas for non-latin words

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about it this way:

```
text.scan(/ #[[:digit:]]?[[:alpha:]]+ /).map{ |s| s.strip[1..-1] }
```

which returns:

```
[
    [0] "box",
    [1] "2good"
]
```

I don't try to do everything in a regex. I prefer to keep them as simple as possible, then filter and mutilate once I've gotten the basic data captured. My reasoning is that regex are more difficult to maintain the more complex they become. I'd rather spend my time doing something else than maintaining patterns.

Comment: I believe part of the question was to match hash tags that may have a number(s) at any position but not ALL numbers in the match. The above scan would just match the sample provided but would not necessarily cover all scenarios required like #343nj12 or #sdnver4 or #sve43klas

Comment: You are assuming that's what was asked for, but it's not specified in the OP's question. It's important to answer the question they ask, unless it's obvious their question is a red-herring. Based on the sample input and output the pattern works. It's an easy adjustment to the pattern to accomodate more complex patterns without it becoming unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\s#([[\d]]?[[a-z]]+\s)/i
```

Output:

```
1.9.3-p194 :010 > text = "Pack my #box with #5 dozen liquor.#jugs link.com/liquor#jugs #2good #first#second"
 => "Pack my #box with #5 dozen liquor.#jugs link.com/liquor#jugs #2good #first#second" 
1.9.3-p194 :011 > puts text.scan /\s#([[\d]]?[[a-z]]+\s)/i 
box 
2good 
 => nil
```

Comment: This would not match tags like #sjdf34ksd. Neither does mine. Need to figure out a better regex.

Comment: Figured it out. Check my answer. Had to use a negative lookahead.