# How to write a hashtag matching regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a problem with writing an regex (in Ruby, but I don't think that it changes anything) that selects all proper hashtags.

I used  `( /(^|\s)(#+)(\w+)(\s|$)/ )`, which doesn't work and I have no idea why.

In this example:

```
#start #middle #middle2 #middle3 bad#example #another#bad#example #end
```

it should mark `#start`, `#middle`, `#middle2`, `#middle3` and `#end`.

Why doesn't my code work and how should a proper regex look?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code request.

Comment: It isn't - the main question is why my code doesn't work - there are plenty of such questions all over here.

Comment: If there are plenty such questions [isn't this a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102746/regex-to-match-hashtags-in-a-sentence-using-ruby)?

Comment: I didn't mean that but ... right - it looks very similar to the one linked by you. Still it'd be great to understand what is wrong with my code :D (but as far as see no one cares about the first question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does `[^#\w](#[\w]*)|^(#[\w]*)` works?

getting an # not following a character, and capturing everything until not a word.

the or case handle the case where the first char is `#`.

Live demo: http://regexr.com/3al01

Comment: Thanks, looks fine but there is just one more condition (I changed it a while ago) - it shouldn't mark anything in this case: #xxx#yyy

Comment: huh.. right, I was thinking about it too, but it depends on what you want, like.. given `#xxx#yyy`, is the whole thing valid? or not? or only `#xxx` is valid?

Comment: There should be spaces around the hash so only #xxx is OK (BTW - do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?)

Comment: I think it is because of the spaces. you are getting `^start ` and leaving `#middle #middle2 #middle3 bad#example #end` which does not start with a space, non it is beginning of the line, so it skip to the next space for matching `space hash some_number_of_char space`, and do only `SPACE#middle2SPACE` is taken.

Comment: I won't say it is the correct way to do, but I would usually grab chars that is not space, so it will grab as much as it can until it hit a space. like `#[^\s]*` a hash tag that followed by not space chars until the next space

Comment: yea, so, it is more like how it works I guess. after it grab the `#startSPACE`, the pointer start at the `#` rather than the `SPACE`... I did read the code, or have any prove, it just seems like it is how it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

As for why the original does not work lets look at each bit

1. `(^|\s)` Start of line or white space
2. `(#+)`  one or more `#`
3. `(\w+)` one or more alphanumeric characters
4. `(\s|$)` white space or end of line

The main problem is a conflict between 1 and 4. When 1 matches white space that white space was already matched in the last group as part 4. So 1 does not exist and the match moves to the next possible

4 is not really needed since 3 will not match white space.

So here is the result

```
(?:^|\s)#(\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iU4dZ3/3

Comment: It matches bad#example and it shouldn't.

Comment: whoops, easy fix though

Comment: Cleanest and shortest solution.

Answer (score 0):

How's this work for you?

```
(#[^\s+]+)
```

This says find a hash tag then everything until a whitespaces.

Comment: Nope, that matches `bad#example`.

Comment: Okay, this one should than. `(^|\s+)(#[^\s+]+)`

Answer (score 0):

One more regex:

```
\B#\w+\b
```

This one doesn't capture whitespaces...

https://regex101.com/r/iU4dZ3/4